# Convergence of a sequence of infimum in a first-countable space

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Let $x_0\in X$ where $X$ is a first-countable topological space, and let $f:X\to [-\infty,\infty]$ be lower semicontinuous. Show that there exists a decreasing sequence $(U_n)$ of open neighborhoods of $x_0$ such that $\inf_{x\in U_n}f(x) $ increases to $f(x_0)$.

My attempt:

Since $X$ is first-countable there exists a sequence $(B_n)$ of open neighborhoods of $x_0$ such that any neighborhood of $x_0$ contains $N_n$ for some $n$. Define the sequence $(U_n)$ of open neighborhoods of $x_0$ by $U_n=B_1\cap \dots \cap B_n$ for each $n$. I claim that $\inf_{x\in U_n}f(x) $ increases to $f(x_0)$.

Let $\lambda<f(x_0)$. Since $f$ is lower semicontinuous there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ such that $$\lambda\leq\inf_{x\in U}f(x)\leq f(x_0) $$

By definition of $(B_n)$ there exists $N\geq 1$ such that $B_N\subset U$. Then for all $n\geq N$ we have

$$\lambda\leq\inf_{x\in U}f(x)\leq \inf_{x\in U_n}f(x) \leq f(x_0) $$

As $\lambda<f(x_0)$ was arbitrary the claim follows.

Comment: You may want to add that $X$ is T_1 or T_2 so that convergence in $X$ is unique.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Why would I need uniqueness?

Comment: Consider an example without separability properties. Now in your case, every point has a countable local base. You can use nets to show the statement of your problem.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Am not sure am following you. The convergence happens in $[-\infty,\infty]$, not in $X$.

Comment: For an nondecreasing countable base $U_n$ of a point $x_0$ choose $x_n\in U_n$. Then $\{x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a sequence convergent to $x_0$ (Here is where you told like separability, say $T_1$) for then the problem reduces to $\liminf_nf(x_n)\geq f(x_0)$. In fact, in any topological $T_1$ space, a function $f$ is l.s.c. iff for any net $x_\alpha\rightarrow x$, $\liminf_\alpha f(x_\alpha)\geq f(x)$.